# Remplazar etiqueta marquee de HTML por efectos con SASS

Tags: html, ionic, ionic3, sass

Estoy teniendo un pequeño problema al usar la etiqueta `<marquee>` de HTML (se que está en desuso o depreciada, pero era la unica que me permitía dar ese efecto), mi texto puede contener hasta 30 caracteres por lo que me es muy dificil mostrarlo en una sola linea, así que por eso tomé la decisión de usar dicha etiqueta.

Realmente la etiqueta funciona y realiza el efecto esperado, pero todo cambia cuando paso a un componente de IONIC diferente al componente donde se encuentra la etiqueta (Se queda pausada u otras veces queda en blanco).

¿Que solución puedo implementar para obtener el mismo efecto?

Gracias!

Comment: Puede que te interese entonces introducir una librería llamada  [ionic-marquee](http://example.com) que hace lo mismo que el _deprecated_ `<marquee>` pero compatible con Ionic.

Comment: No sabia que Ionic contaba con dicha librería. Voy a investigar al respecto...Gracias!